# function access of modifiable variables

Tags: python, scope, callback, global-variables

I have the following bits of code:

- `my_object`: some arbitrary object
- `generate_object()`: a function that generates a new (potentially modified) version of `my_object`.  It is expensive to run, and I'd prefer to avoid it when possible.
- `callback1()`: a callback function that uses `my_object` as is.
- `callback2()`: a callback function that requires an updated version of `my_object`, i.e. `my_object = generate_object()`

I'd like to find an idiomatic way to achieve the above, but keep running into difficulties.  Is this a good use-case for defining `my_object` in the global namespace, reading it in `callback1()`, and modifying it in `callback2()`?  Alternative suggestions welcome.

Comment: You can just use the `global` keyword to share variable between functions. But I'd avoid global variables, and opt for using a class instead.

Comment: Yes: I'm running into issues 'modifying local variable'... I suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree with this method.  Could you provide an example of exactly what you mean?

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://ideone.com/vyxMCJ. Like I said though, I'd opt for using a class instead. Make your global variable(s) attributes of your class, and your functions methods.

Comment: thanks - I was looking for an example of your suggested method, but I think I can get it.  Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help out. I'm sure you'll get it!